# How get count of distinct of a field per (group by) another field MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have some documents like these:

```
{ "type" : "A", "item" : "I1"}
{ "type" : "A", "item" : "I2"}
{ "type" : "A", "item" : "I2"}
{ "type" : "A", "item" : "I2"}
{ "type" : "A", "item" : "I3"}
{ "type" : "B", "item" : "I4"}
{ "type" : "B", "item" : "I4"}
{ "type" : "B", "item" : "I5"}
```

I want to find the count of distinct "item" per each "type", like as:

```
{ "type" : "A", "item-count" : 3}
{ "type" : "B", "item-count" : 2}
```

Is there any idea how I can write a MongoDB query? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$group` by both type and item
- `$group` by just type and count sum

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        type: "$type",
        item: "$item"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.type",
      "item-count": { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0LGfR_ljZCh)